# d3.json not parsing my JSON correctly?

Tags: json, d3.js

I am attempting to switch my code to allow an external JSON file to be referenced. See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/nk508p1p/), line 62.

However, I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined at update
```

meaning (I assume) that my json file somehow isn't getting parsed correctly. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the variable with `json` data directly in the `d3.json` call. It needs to be an `url` to a json file either someplace online or somewhere on your local machine.

So instead, all you have to do is get rid of the `d3.json` call and use the data variable directly.

```
var graph = data; //set your graph variable equal to your data var

update(graph);  // pass it directly to your update function. No need for d3.json
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b4to2mqe/